# dynamic plotting working intraday but not dailly

Tags: plot, pine-script

I'd like to plot some sma depending on timeframe I am viewing at, if it is daily or intraday.

Basically, I use security function to plot sma referred to 20 min timeframe.
v0, v1, v7 and v8 are lenght variables being used with sma function.
m0, m1, m7 and m8 are variables which contain the floating value for plotting.

I use a workaround to do not plot sma which I don't need, assigning a "1" value to length variable and then assign "na" to floating value.

It works perfectly in intraday, but in daily timeframe it's always plotting a sma with "1" as lenght value and not v7 and v8 values. I really can't understand why. Anyone could help?

```
//@version=4
study(title="test", overlay=true)

//values for plot
colore_blu = #0000ff
spessorelinea = input(defval=2, title="Spessore linee")

// is timeframe intraday?
intra = timeframe.isintraday

//if timeframe is intraday than assign the right value to varaibles, otherwise assign 1
v0 = intra ? 13 : 1
v1 = intra ? 26 : 1

//if timeframe is not intraday than assign the right value to variables, otherwise assign 1
v7 = intra ? 1 : 1664
v8 = intra ? 1 : 3328

//display values for length
plot(v0, color=color.blue)
plot(v1, color=color.aqua)
plot(v7, color= color.maroon)
plot(v8, color=color.black)

//if length variable is 1 then sma is not available
m0 = v0 == 1 ? na : security(syminfo.tickerid, "20", sma(close, v0))
m1 = v1 == 1 ? na : security(syminfo.tickerid, "20", sma(close, v1))
m7 = v7 == 1 ? na : security(syminfo.tickerid, "20", sma(close, v7))
m8 = v8 == 1 ? na : security(syminfo.tickerid, "20", sma(close, v8))

// just for test, if i put values instead of variables v7 and v8, plotting is correct
m7_test = security(syminfo.tickerid, "20", sma(close, 1664))
m8_test = security(syminfo.tickerid, "20", sma(close, 3328))

//plotting sma
plot(m0, title="T-3", color=colore_blu, linewidth=spessorelinea, style=plot.style_line)
plot(m1, title="T-2", color=color.aqua, linewidth=spessorelinea, style=plot.style_line)
plot(m7, title="T+4", color=color.maroon, linewidth=spessorelinea, style = plot.style_line)
plot(m8, title="T+5 annuale", color=color.black, linewidth=spessorelinea, style = plot.style_line)
plot(m7_test, title="T+4", color=color.maroon, linewidth=spessorelinea, style = plot.style_cross)
plot(m8_test, title="T+5 annuale", color=color.black, linewidth=spessorelinea, style = plot.style_cross)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you need plotted when you are not at intraday resolution. This plots the 13 and 26 MAs at the chart's resolution at >intraday resolutions.

```
//@version=4
study(title="test", overlay=true)

//values for plot
colore_blu = #0000ff
spessorelinea = input(defval=2, title="Spessore linee")

// is timeframe intraday?
intra = timeframe.isintraday

m0 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "20", sma(close, 13))
m1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "20", sma(close, 26))
m7 = sma(close, 13)
m8 = sma(close, 26)

//plotting sma
plot(intra ? m0 : na, title="T-3", color=colore_blu, linewidth=spessorelinea, style=plot.style_line)
plot(intra ? m1 : na, title="T-2", color=color.aqua, linewidth=spessorelinea, style=plot.style_line)
plot(not intra ? m7 : na, title="T+4", color=color.maroon, linewidth=spessorelinea, style = plot.style_line)
plot(not intra ? m8 : na, title="T+5 annuale", color=color.black, linewidth=spessorelinea, style = plot.style_line)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: As you did, I wanted 13 and 26 sma in intraday graphs, while 1664 and 3328 only in daily graphs.
Putting ternary operator in plot functions make it easier and actually it works. Thank you very much.